# MS Word file has no icon

Tags: ms-word

Suddenly my MS word files have no icon (as the image). Please help by a solution.

[Image showing MS word file without icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jap0t.jpg)

Comment: Is it opening OK? Then What is the problem? Use superuser instead for this type of questions. This has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Sir, It is being opened with MS Office The problem with the icon.. Sorry for an irrelevant question.

Comment: run "appwiz.cpl" and go to office and select quick repair... that worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the OS can't find a default program associated with the file type.

In windows 7, click start -> default programs -> Associate a file type or protocol with a program.

Then just link the .doc files (or whatever) with MS Word and the icons should now show the MS Word icon as the file is associated with that program.

In Windows 8/10, the exact steps might not be the same but you will still have to set a default program to handle .doc files

Comment: If you see the screenshot, The os is actually identifying the programme as seen in the details. So it is hiding the filetype for known files. It's XP not windows 7 if you look at the screenshot.